# Can't create a new python 3.5 env with the latest download of Anaconda

Tags: anaconda, conda, python-3.5

I just uninstalled an older version of Anaconda and installed the latest download (3.4) from their site, minutes ago.  I tried to create a new env called Py35 using the conda command: conda create -n Py35 python=3.5 anaconda

I got the following error:

> ....
> Solving  package specifications:....
>
> Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications.
>
> Generating Hint:
>
> [    COMPLETE    ] #####....: 100%
>
> Hint: the following packages conflict with each other:
>
> - python 3.5*
> - anaconda
>
> Use 'conda info python' etc. to see the dependencies for each package.
>
> Note the following features are enabled:
>
> - vc14
>   ....

So I conda info'd both python and anaconda and found that Python 3.5 is available in this download, but the packages I need from Anaconda 2.3.0 all have python 3.4 dependencies and I'm not able to create an env with them and python v3.5.

I suppose if I have to I'll just create a 3.4 env, but why does this Conda page (http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html) suggest that it's possible to create a 3.5 env with the full Anaconda pkg, when Anaconda is apparently lacking?

Thanks for your input.
Ana

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the reason I can't create a python 3.5/Anaconda env, even though python 3.5 is available in the latest Anaconda download, is that the WINDOWS version of Anaconda is still python 3.4 dependent and will not be updated to python 3.5 until the end of this month in the release of Anaconda 2.4.

I received this information from Carlos Cordoba a Spyder developer that answered my question in the Anaconda Public Google group.  Then I Googled for the actual release date and came up with this page: https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer/python-35-support-anaconda

Best,
Ana

Comment: I just installed Anaconda3 2.4.1, I then ran following: 

    conda update conda
    conda update --all

Both ran fine, then conda update anaconda failed with the above conflict.  Is there a resolution to this?